# CodeMirror- Change color of highlighted Diff lines

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm trying to change the color of the highlighted diff lines on code mirror but I'm having trouble finding the correct style to edit.

The color I have is exactly the yellow you see on:
http://codemirror.net/demo/merge.html#

I'm trying to change it to green for adds and red for deletes. Could someone shed some light? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the "merge.css" asset into your project like they do at the top of that example, which includes:

```
.CodeMirror-merge-r-chunk {
    background: #ffffe0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the correct element. Is there a way to have different colors for each of the left and right panes?